# Track Email with Google user contents img resource and redirecting to my website

Tags: email, links, tracking

I'm using Email tracking services of some Email sender company. It is achieved through requesting img resource when opening email. Here is the code inserted into HTML message:

`<img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/TObr7aARe70s=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.mywebsite.com/TrackEmail?j=eyJ1IjoiMQ4In0%3D&amp;r=0.614693022798747.gif" width="2" height="1">`

I'm interested in how eventually the request will come to my website. Can anyone please explain me? I think the magic is somewhere in this part `...d-e1-ft#htt...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at this email in Gmail, I believe that the googleusercontent.com was added to your image.  [Google recently announced](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/12/gmail-blows-up-e-mail-marketing-by-caching-all-images-on-google-servers/) that they are now caching all images shown in Gmail on their own servers as a user privacy protection.

This may break some email tracking.  It will certainly limit the amount of information you can gather about Gmail users that open emails.  You will no longer be able to see what browser they use, for example.

The announcement article gives some more information about how the Google image proxy actually works.  Google serves the images from their site, but has their server request it from your server the first time it is used.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Stephen! So what you're saying is that my original email contained only this part  - _http://www.mywebsite.com/TrackEmail?j=eyJ1IjoiMQ4In0%3D&amp;r=0.614693022798747.gif_, but then google itself added the first part?

Comment: I guess you're right. I've found the same approach for Yandex (russian mail service) - _`src="https://cache.mail.yandex.net/mail/edd41c3205985a91959aca6e6924c3d5/www.inreado.com/TrackEmail?j=eyJ1IjoiMzdDND...`_

Comment: So basically caching doesn't break basic tracking system. However, I don't understand how they can track if certain email was opened second time? I assume that google wouldn't make second request to my server for the image since it's already cached.

Comment: It would break tracking of second open.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But they can show me statistics about the consequent opens, any ideas on how they manage to track that?

Comment: Their statistics are wrong when gmail is involved.

Comment: Got you, thanks! I guess their statistics could also be wrong for some other mail services, like `yandex.ru` since it also caches pics.

Comment: I use Thunderbird for mail and block all images by default, so their statistics should never count users like me.   Open rate statistics will never be completely accurate.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Do you think the statistics will be biased toward less or more users opening an email?

Comment: More users will open their mail than will be able to be tracked.

Answer (score 1):

Google is implementing cache so we can only do one thing is need to validate the time. If we received the request within 5 seconds of mail sent we need to block that as its google cache. If we received the request after 5 seconds we can count that.